# Installing USR 5422 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, drivers, wifi

I was trying to set up the USR5422 USB adapter. It worked fine for the first time, but since then it freezes the computer most of the time.

What commands can I fire to see what's going on?

I followed the instructions on [Ubuntu Forums thread titled How do I get a USR 5422 usb wlan
adapter to work under hardy heron?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=781337)

**Update:** It's stopped freezing, but is unable to connect to the wireless network.

My network authentication has the following properties:

- Security type: WPA-Personal
- Encryption type: TKIP

I've got the following settings in the linux laptop:

- Security: WPA & WPA2 Personal

Comment: This looks useful, if a little painful. The poster got it working well in the end. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1838434

Comment: Please answer your own question if you got it to work, for future reference.

Comment: Not successful till date

Comment: What drivers is this using? This site claims you can use p54usb, which I believe is the prism drivers mentioned in the ubuntu forum in the comment above. Just looking to understand where this Q&A is at.

Answer (score 1):

Should you wish to view the detailed information of a USB device, use **lsusb**

```
$ lsusb -d <device id> -vvv
```

For further USB / hardware troubleshooting, refer to the detailed answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting to get the correct driver.

From your description, the USB adapter is working but the connection fails. You might just want to try to reset your Wifi password and/or a different encryption protocol.